# jsonschema - oneOf keyword behaves unexpectedly

Tags: json, python-3.x, validation, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I'm trying to validate a `json` payload in Python, using `jsonschema 3.0.1`, that roughly looks like that (simplified to the troublesome part):

```
{
    "request": {
        "topic": {
            "param1": "bleep beep topic",
            "param2": "bloop boop topic"
        },
        "message": {
            "param1": "bleep beep message",
            "param2": "bloop boop message"
        }
    }
}
```

A valid request is expected to have two fields: a `topic` and matching `message`.

Each of them can consist of either `param1` only or **both** `param1` and `param2`.

- valid: `topic { param1, param2 }, body { param1, param2 }`
- valid: `topic { param1 }, body { param1 }`

But it can't have neither `topic` with only `param1` and body with both, nor a `topic` with both and body with only `param2`:

- invalid: `topic { param1, param2 }, body { param1 }`
- invalid: `topic { param1}, body { param1, param2 }`

Because the content of one node depends on the content of another node, I wasn't able to use the `dependencies` keyword or the `if-then-else` construction, so I've tried to use the `oneOf`, and provide a list of valid subschemas with references to the `one_param` and `both_params` versions of the field, like so:

```py
from jsonschema import validate

one_param = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "param1": {
            "type": "string",
        }
    },
    "required": ["param1"]
}

both_params = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "param1": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "param2": {
            "type": "string",
        }
    },
    "required": ["param1", "param2"]
}

test_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "request": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "topic": one_param,
                        "message": one_param
                    },

                    "required": ["topic", "message"]
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "topic": both_params,
                        "message": both_params
                    },

                    "required": ["topic", "message"]
                }
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior of the validator is not what I expected: it fails on the case with both params, and successfully validates the case with one param or mismatched params.

**Why does my validation schema not work as I've explained?**

---

Here's entire test that I wrote for that purpose:

- `good_1` case fails validation
- `good_2`, `bad_1` and `bad_2` cases are successfully validated

```py
from jsonschema import validate

one_param = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "param1": {
            "type": "string",
        }
    },
    "required": ["param1"]
}

both_params = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "param1": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "param2": {
            "type": "string",
        }
    },
    "required": ["param1", "param2"]
}

test_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "request": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "topic": one_param,
                        "message": one_param
                    },
                    "required": ["topic", "message"]
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "topic": both_params,
                        "message": both_params
                    },
                    "required": ["topic", "message"]
                }
            ],
        }
    }
}

good_1 = {
    "request": {
        "topic": {
            "param1": "bleep beep",
            "param2": "bloop boop"
        },
        "message": {
            "param1": "bleep beep message",
            "param2": "bloop boop message"
        }
    }
}

good_2 = {
    "request": {
        "topic": {
            "param1": "bleep beep"
        },
        "message": {
            "param1": "bleep beep message"
        }
    }
}

bad_1 = {
    "request": {
        "topic": {
            "param1": "bleep beep",
        },
        "message": {
            "param1": "bleep beep message",
            "param2": "bloop boop message with no matching topic"
        }
    }
}

bad_2 = {
    "request": {
        "topic": {
            "param1": "bleep beep",
            "param2": "bloop boop topic with no matching message"
        },
        "message": {
            "param1": "bleep beep message"
        }
    }
}

validate(good_1, test_schema)  # should validate
validate(good_2, test_schema)  # should validate
validate(bad_1, test_schema)  # should fail
validate(bad_2, test_schema)  # should fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `oneOf`, each item in the array (a subschema) is applied to the data. If you test each of the individual subschemas in your `oneOf`, what happens?

You'll find that BOTH are valid!

Your `"one_param"` schema needs to make sure that including `param2` would cause it to fail. You can use `additionalProperties` to do this...

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "param1": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "param1"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I think you were assuming that only properties defined in `properties` are allowed, but that's not the case, hence the need for you to also define them in `required`.

You can see this working by trying the schema on [https://jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEAXAngBwKasiiAPYBGAVjgMZqoA0CyqWATkbs2gJY5j6JxJkhZjgCOAVx40o-BkMbF4OAPIAzPgG0585AJ07UmXH1SkK1Otv2EWbHB268Ze6-MNtOlPi9dv02PBlTcippekFfISZWdi4ebytIhSwAQ2YUgFsARgSIpL8jQIJUMDRmTngAc1REpIBfWtc68PyFEQlOEQATTUbfJjTMnJA+-QBdFtbUFK6uzi4ieBSAGwAFGPs4pwJVFbA8PKbJyNQMnjAUyqLZQ-7-YyDiEIsQY6Touwd451HrAfTsrlWgZ7tcSmUKtURrdIg0YdZmr8-O1xJ0cD0ZFp4a5-kMatidBMkVEQDM5gslmsNl9tohdst9sS4bC3vpUCi0RiCFj8u4sJ5LASFGcwBcrvjImM+oj4T4-qCTE9zGFfh9Yo4ge90B4vD8hSTCoqzKFBcC1ZsNXrgclBoCrdaFIbHqVylUJdaZQ7cRkAEyar0K50Qt3Qh3M1qeqYgDndXr6vypAHDVlaxOZP2h1pE+OEMnzTiLFbrT5bPj0xn6yMnEAisXXOXVp3FJUm17E5LU0v2s0gNN2ggNqNNwguyHu4FVqN9jMD9sg4fg11QufIcP5SfVmPouMBvvJlc2W0ZufZnt5ilFzuWnZ7A7r34bkFbrmIHlatA601a2uXQK-KXwmuQgAfI4ZwnUrwgJwUAwFY7JiJIpT+vOn7dnce6KiQyw4DgWCICQOFYOOOiPsK5y-shOK9rawzNlhhH4QxP7ipm+hAeBIB1EAA). I've pre-loaded the link with the updated schema and instance.

As an aside, you can use `definitions` and `$ref` to avoid repeating subschemas, should you wish to save your schema to a single json file.